# Conversion of javascript into android in appmobi

Tags: appmobi

can anyone tell me if there is any specific file by which appmobi converts js and html to java and xml and how its compatible for both iphone and andriod ?
is there any tool used in appmobi for conversion process ? 
How does the native script bridge API source code they have given in appmobi website help for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The appMobi XDK is based off of [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com). There isn't actually a conversion between JS/HTML to Java or Objective-C -- the app remains in its form (JS/HTML/CSS), and is executed within a native application runtime container (like a web browser). If you have not done so already, download the appMobi app-lab application for your smart phone platform, and use the Test Anywhere feature. If you've done that, you'll have a better idea what they're talking about with native execution.

I've built several demo apps for the Mashery / appMobi project, including some walk-thru screencasts. Check out the following URLs:

- http://www.appmobi.com/mashery
- https://github.com/mashery/mashery-appmobi-demos

Regards,
Neil
http://developer.mashery.com